# Xamarin iOS swap image in bundle at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I want to allow my app to download images from the web to be placed in /images and then displayed in the UI - this is to allow branding specific images to be downloaded for a multitenant app.

The app downloads the image fine and places the image into the /Images folder

However when trying to load the image using `UIImage.FromFile` it always returns null - even though I know full well the image is there!

I know UIImage.FromBundle caches stuff so I chose to use FromFile but this doesn't seem to work?!

Is there something I need to do to make this work? Or am I pushing my luck a little?

I am using the following to create the file path:

```
public static UIImage SafeClaim_Logo = UIImage.FromFile(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath +"/Images/Logo.png");
```

The following is the code I use to download and save the file - the file path from the above is the same below when I inspect it

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient ();
var clientResponse = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath + path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
 {
     var bytes = clientResponse;
     fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
 }
```

Comment: Show the code where you create the file path. I think there is something wrong.

Comment: You can't put images into the bundle. Use the documents path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app bundle is read-only so you can't change or add something in there at runtime.

All content created at runtime should be stored in your documents or cache folders.

You can get the documents folder by calling:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```

Answer (score 0):

One good place to store this kind of files is the *Library/* folder. On **iOS 7** you can access it using:

```
var libraryFolderPath = Path.GetFullPath(
    Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
       Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "..", "Library"));
```

On **iOS 8**:

```
var url = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetUrls (
    NSSearchPathDirectory.LibraryDirectory, NSSearchPathDomain.User) [0];
var libraryFolderPath = url.Path;
```

The reason is explained by [Xamarin documentation](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_the_file_system/):

> The Library directory is a good place to store files that are not
>   created directly by the user, such as databases or other
>   application-generated files. **The contents of this directory are never
>   exposed to the user via iTunes.**
>
> You can create your own subdirectories in Library; however, there are
>   already some system-created directories here that you should be aware
>   of, including Preferences and Caches.
>
> The contents of this directory (except for the Caches subdirectory)
>   are backed up by iTunes. Custom directories that you create in Library
>   will be backed up.

If you need to enable iTunes file sharing and expose the content of the *Documents/* folder, your files are not visible to the user.